# variance and covariance in compound symmetry

Tags: mixed-model

For the covariance structure of compound symmetry in SAS help documentation, the variance in the diagonal is square(σ) + σ1, and the covariance off diagonal is σ1. Both variance and covariance include σ1. Could someone tell why σ1 is part of variance? What's the relationship of variance and covariance in compound symmetry structure? Looking forward to your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know which documentation you are referring to, so I can't speak specifically to SAS.  Your question is about parameterizing a form of covariance matrix.  Although you *could* use the diagonal and off-diagonal terms for your parameters, you risk creating invalid covariance matrices if the off-diagonal terms exceed the diagonal ones. The parameterization you appear to describe looks like it helps the user avoid that mistake.  But, as I said at the outset, I'm just guessing.  Maybe you could give us more context and an explicit reference?

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I am referring to Table 79.19 under the link https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/statug/statug_mixed_syntax14.htm#statug.mixed.mixedecovstruct. Look at the table, you will see the matrix for compound symmetry structure. Could you kindly take a look at it? Sorry that I don't know to copy the table here.